# Synchronized Facebook and website?

Tags: facebook, vue.js, sdk

When I use Facebook JavaScript SDK, I login in my website by facebook. It login facebook too. And when I logout facebook in my web, it logout facebook too. Why and how can I fix?

I only use

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

When login by facebook to my website, I only want to get information of facebook account.

Comment: What do you want to fix?

Comment: I only want to get facebook account information. And when I login or logout in my website. My facebook page doesn't login or logout same.

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: How this logout behaves, depends on what conditions the user logged in under. If they were not logged in to Facebook at the time they logged in to your app (so calling the app login triggered FB login), then they get logged out of your app _and_ Facebook at the same time. If they were logged in to Facebook before already, then they get logged out of your app only, but not Facebook, so that they can continue their browsing session there.